# Java Gradle find out dependency's jar file name

Tags: java, gradle

I have a java gradle project. I have a dependency.

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":mymodule")
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.2.RELEASE'
}
```

Where can I find and use exact jar file name of both my custom module and spring dependency jar to process it further in composing application's libs, folders, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stick this in a new task:

```
project.configurations.compile.each{ println it}
```

Or, for just one specific dependency:

```
println project.configurations.compile.find {it.name.startsWith("something") }
```

However, if you're looking to create distributable packages including dependencies, you really should look into the [gradle application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html).